# Clear Jenkins workspace after 'n' builds

Tags: java, scala, jenkins

I am using Jenkins for continuous integration win my scala application. I have two modules in every project. One for Scala and one for UI (Angular with bower and npm). Sometimes, in the UI project, some of the commands are not getting executed properly. However, if I clean the jenkins workspace and run again, it works fine. 
I am looking for some plugin or another solution by which the workspace can be cleared before every 10th build or so.

Using [Workspace Cleanup Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Workspace+Cleanup+Plugin) , it is possible to clear the workspace before/after build. But then the build takes more time to complete since many files/jars needs to be downloaded

Comment: You can exclude to delete the jar files, but you can also use Nexus to keep your libraries close.

Comment: No, I donot want to delete the workspace everytime.. I guess I should try writing some shell scripts to achieve it..